How does exponentials being eigenfunctions of differentiation relate to the solution of linear differential equations?
I know that exponentials are eigenfunctions of the derivative operator since $$\frac{d}{dx}\left\{ e^{\lambda x} \right\}=\lambda e^{\lambda x}$$ I also know that if a linear constant coefficients differential equation of the form $$a_ny^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots +a_{2}y''+a_{1}y'+a_{0}y=0$$ has a charactersitic equation with $n$ different roots, the general solution  is thus of the form $$y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_ie^{\lambda_i x}$$But are these two facts related somehow, why exactly are exponentials so fundamental to the solution of linear differential equations? Is it just because when we assume $y=e^{\lambda x}$ we get a polynomial in $\lambda$ ?

I don't know what more you're looking for.  The fact that the derivative of $\exp(\lambda x)$ is $\lambda \exp(\lambda x)$ means that $y = \exp(\lambda x)$ satisfies $a_n y^{(n)} + \ldots + a_0 y = (a_n \lambda^n + \ldots + a_0) y$, so this is $0$ if $a_n \lambda^n + \ldots + a_0 = 0$.

If $Av=\lambda v$, then $p(A)v = p(\lambda) v$ for any polynomial $p$. The left hand side can be written as $Ly = p(D)y$,where $D$ is the differential operator. With $v(x)= e^{\lambda x}$, we get $p(D)v = p(\lambda)v$, so solving $p(\lambda) = 0$ will provide a solution to $Ly = 0$. There is more to it, but this is why it is useful.

not an answer at all, but someone else could develop this ideas: since linear ODEs can be transformed through linear operators, like the Fourier transform, you could inherit their kernels, in the specific case of the Fourier Transform their eigenfunction are Hermite polynomials, so maybe by just saying that exponencials are the eigenfunctions of linear ODEs you could be getting short in cases where multiplicity of the egeinfunction is greater than one.

Write $D = \frac{d}{dx}$. The relationship is that a linear ODE with constant coefficients can be written in the form
$$\left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k D^k \right) y = 0$$
so we have $p(D) y = 0$ where $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of the ODE. Now we have the following important general result:

Polynomial spectral mapping theorem: If $T : V \to V$ is a linear map with an eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $p$ is a polynomial, then $p(T)$ also has eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $p(\lambda)$.

The proof is an easy calculation of $p(T) v$.

Corollary: $p(D) e^{\lambda t} = p(\lambda) e^{\lambda t}$ is equal to zero iff $p(\lambda) = 0$.

This is in some sense just a way to organize the calculation of what happens when you plug in $e^{\lambda t}$. But these results admit a converse: you can show very generally that the space of vectors such that $p(T) v = 0$ consists of generalized eigenvectors of $T$ with eigenvalues the roots of the polynomial $p$, and when you work out what the generalized eigenvectors of $D$ are you get the functions $t^k e^{\lambda t}$. So you get all solutions this way, not just the easy ones; an abstract explanation of why it was reasonable to "guess" these solutions; and an abstract explanation of why there aren't any others.
Exactly the same theorems can then be reused on the case that $T$ is the shift operator $T(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots) = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots )$ acting on sequences, and they solve linear recurrences with constant coefficients for you too!

[+1] To complete: let $Y:=(y^{(n-1)}\ \cdots\ y'\ y)^T$, $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}a_{n-1}&a_{n-2}&\cdots&a_0\-1&0&\cdots&0\0&-1&\ddots&\vdots\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&0\0&\cdots&0&–1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then (assuming wlog $a_n=1$) $a_ny^{(n)}+\cdots+a_1y'+a_0y=0\iff A'+AY=0\iff(e^{xA}Y)'=0\iff Y(x)=e^{-xA}Y(0)$. If $A$ is diagonalizable (e.g., all roots of the characteristic equation are distinct; equivalently all eigenvalues of $A$ are simple), the spectral projection-form $A=\sum_\lambda \lambda\Pi_\lambda$ leads to $e^{-xA}=\sum_{\lambda}e^{-\lambda x}\Pi_\lambda$ and the stated expression of $y$.
